# variable in a string not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, variables

here is the code:

> const textIn = fs.readFileSync('./txt/input.txt', 'utf-8');

> const textOut = 'this is the addition: ${textIn}, \nCreated on ${Date.now()}';

> fs.writeFileSync('./txt/output.txt', textOut);

The content of the input.txt file is "hello world". What should happen is the content of the output.txt file should read "this is the addition: hello world 1614606057967.

but it reads...

> this is the addition: ${textIn}

> Created on ${Date.now()}

Any ideas why?

Comment: Use backticks(`) not inverted comma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [these Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), you need to enclose your string in backticks, not single quotes.

So you want:

```
const textOut = `this is the addition: ${textIn}, \nCreated on ${Date.now()}`;
```

Comment: @sunday - glad I could help! If this answer solved your issue, you could 'accept' it by clicking the checkmark near the upvote and downvote buttons to let others know this solution works.